Motor brake circuit using MOSFETs

I want to connect a DC motor to an Arduino or ESP32 which has speed control as well as a brake.

When I send a LOW output to the top opto and a PWM signal to the lower opto, I want the motor to have variable speed.
When I send a HIGH signal to the top opto and a LOW signal to the bottom opto, I want the motor to be braked.

I know that when both are switched HIGH, that it would be a short and smoke will come out, therefore there will be a short delay (100 ms) between switching.
Will the above circuit work?

why not get rid of the BJT and just connect pin 4 of your upper optoisolator to the mosfet gate, and pin 3 to GND?

You circuit above needs a resistor between the optocoupler and the NPN transistor.
If you want less smoke you can do this:

Else delete the PNP transistor and ground the opto-coupler emitter.
